# Switch from HTTP to HTTPS in Beego

Tags: http, go, https, beego

I try to switch from HTTP to HTTPS:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Printf("About to listen on 8080. Go to https://127.0.0.1:8080/")
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8080", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
crypto/tls: failed to parse key PEM data
```

My application is running in HTTP mode now and I want it to run in HTTPS mode.

Can anyone suggest how to make it work in HTTPS?

Comment: Are you sure `cert.pem` and `key.pem` files are in the proper (current working directory) folder? Try passing absolute paths.

Comment: @icza, yes it is in the same folder.Even if try to pass the absolute path its giving same error.

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that the `key.pem` file cannot be parsed (could be invalid or lacking permission to read its content). Make sure the file is valid and sufficient permissions are set.

For testing purposes, use the `generate_cert.go` in the [`crypto/tls`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/) package to generate valid `cert.pem` and `key.pem` files.

To generate, run the following command (windows):

```
go run %GOROOT%/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go -host="127.0.0.1"
```

Linux:

```
go run $GOROOT/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go -host="127.0.0.1"
```